# How to search within the app that I bought in Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store

I bought an app (.99 cents) a few years ago. I try to use a keyword to find the app in my Google Play, but it is not easy. In the last couple years I downloaded/installed 200+ free and paid. If I go to that 200+ app list to find search one by one, it is very time consuming. If I search the keyword within Google play directly, Google Play will give me ALL apps with the keywords no matter I downloaded or not. How to search within the app that I bought in Google Play? Thaks

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

- Login to your Google account from your PC
- Go to https://play.google.com/apps
- Hit Ctrl+f (or command + f on Mac) and type the name of your app, and look for it.
- Click the app name when you find it.

Now, you can either note down the exact name of the app and the publisher and install manually from the Play Store on phone, or, just click the Install button (make sure your phone is on and has a data plan/wifi), select your device, click Install.

Comment: Is there any solution that works on phones too?

Comment: Using "show desktop version" in Chrome/Firefox on Android, maybe? (I haven't tried this.)

Comment: Yes, that works, but: One has to click "Show More" then scroll down until new items stop appearing (this is similar on PC too).

Comment: Ok, this is bizarre! The search bar says "0 of 0" results, yet the page has jumped to the first app that actually matches the exact text I typed.  Unfortunately, I'm not able to find the "next" app this way...

Comment: @Michael Hmm, seems this is happening because it is dynamically loading entries... if I keep scrolling to the bottom until there is nothing else to load, then the search works properly.